# Input immediately loses focus after click on Android

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, twitter-typeahead

I'm trying to solve a problem where on Android phones, when I tap on my input box, it immediately loses focus. I am using the `twitter-typeahead` library to power the input box.

The chain of events is:

1. Click(tap) on my input box
2. The input boxes gains focus momentarily, and fires a click event
3. Input box loses focus

Here's what I've tried:

**Use `preventDefault` and `preventPropogation` in the click handler**

```
    myInput.on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.preventPropogation();
    });
```

Result: No effect (input box still loses focus)

**2. Firing a focus event in the click handler**

```
    myInput.on('click', function(e){
        myInput.focus()
        // setTimeout(function() { myInput.focus() }, 250); // or this
    });
```

Result: Same as above

Does anybody have any other solutions for me to try?

Comment: does the keyboard also disappears??

Comment: are you using jquery-mobile?

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem. I've been fighting it all day. Does the keyboard stay open on iOS? My problem is only on Android. Also, would you happen to be using the jquery jscrollpane library?

Comment: @tsteve Yes it says open on iOS. We are only using snap.js. werid one isn't it

Comment: @a53-416 Yeah, very weird. Maybe my answer below will help.

Answer (score -1):

I just fixed a similar problem by only including a script that was causing the problem (jquery jscrollpane) on pages where the script is absolutely necessary.

Also, there was a div with position: fixed that was causing a problem. I added the following to the div in css:

```
.top-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: white;
  /* Add these below. Important part. */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Finally, after two days, the problem was fixed.